# Hex to decimal number headache

Tags: php, objective-c, ieee-754

I am confused as to how a series of bytes turn into a decimal number.

When I log the value of (NSData *) data1 I get:

```
(lldb) po data1
<00000000 207ce340 62706c69 73743030 d4000100 02000300 04000500 0612c012 c1582476 ... ...>
```

The first 8 bytes are supposed to contain a number, which the code extracts as follows:

```
memcpy(&doubleNumber, [data1 bytes], sizeof(double));
```

How do the first 8 bytes (which I guess are `00000000 207ce340`, right?) of data1 give the decimal number **39905** ??

**Edit**

The context of this question is needing to do the conversion in PHP: given the hex representation, how can one in PHP convert the number and get the decimal (actually it should be a **float**) 39905?

The answer to this question is in one of the comments below.

Comment: There is a whole big specification that tells how the number is encoded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Do you know the how the number is encoded in the byte stream (i.e. big endian or little endian)?  Do you know what format `NSData` is printing its contents?  Using `double` to hold a byte count is extremely unusual as you cannot have partial bytes, so the whole encoding scheme might be flawed..

Comment: I see... it is much more complicated than I thought. @Sulthan, I don't know how to use the iEEE Floatation Point doc.

Comment: It's not converting from hex, you're looking at a hexadecimal representation of the bits. Those bits are how `39905.0` is represented. So nothing is really "turning into" anything - you're looking at two different interpretations of the same bits.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I don't have the code that generates the `NSData`. It is done by an application I was given a long time ago. What I am trying to do is to replicate in PHP the encoding and decoding of the data. My first step is to understand how the first 8 bytes turn to a number (the length of a string embedded in the rest of `NSData`)

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I understand now what the hex string is about. I am able using PHP's pack/unpack (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) to do the same in PHP.

Comment: For the sake of completion, in PHP I can get the `float` value represented by the hex number `00000000 207ce340` by doing: `$binarydata64 = pack('H*', '00000000207ce340'); $float64 = unpack("d", $binarydata64);`

Answer (score 3):

Using Wikipedia, and various online endian and IEEE 754 converters, I believe I have an answer to your question, "How do the first 8 bytes (which I guess are 00000000 207ce340, right?) of data1 give the decimal number 39905 ?"

```
00000000207ce340  Your starting value

40e37c2000000000  Switch to Big Endian to simplify following analysis

sign (leading) bit = 0  i.e. (0)100 in binary
exponent = 0x40e = 1038
IEEE 754 exponent bias = 1023
fraction = 0x37c2000000000 / 2**52 = 980901810929664 / 2**52

value = 2**(exponent − exponent bias) × (1.0 + fraction)

value = 2**(1038 - 1023) * (1.0 + (980901810929664 / 2**52))

value = 39905.0
```

Or in Unix dc:

```
16 k
2 1038 1023 - ^ 1.0 980901810929664 2 52 ^ / + * p
39905.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks @cdlane! That's an impressive piece of computation. I was actually looking for an easy to code (in PHP) solution and the following two statements do that: `$binarydata64 = pack('H*', '00000000207ce340'); $float64 = unpack("d", $binarydata64);`

Comment: But that's not the question you asked, @Sleiman.  PHP only appears in one comment (before this.)  What will folks coming to this page, based on a search, expect to find since PHP isn't part of the title nor question nor tags?  Even if I didn't anticipate the question you should have asked, is it a good answer to the one you did ask?  (Won't I get flak for answering the question I personally think someone should have asked instead of the one they actually did?)

Comment: You have a good point, @cdlane. I will edit the question accordingly. I am afraid I cannot though select your answer as the correct one because I would have to check its correctness and that would require time and effort which I don't have at the moment. You do get +1 from me for your efforts though.